# Micropython + pylance: "bytes is incompatible with int" error

Tags: micropython, pylance

I'm trying to create several int constants for my module, initialized from the hex values. Pylance keeps complaining about the type conversion errors, but I don't see why and how.

Consider the following code:

```
from micropython import const
_AHT21_I2CADDR_DEFAULT: int = const(0x38) #Default I2C address
_AHT21_CMD_CALIBRATE: bytes = const(0xE1)  # Calibration command
```

For the second line, the error message it shows is:

> Expression of type "int | bytes | str | Tuple[Unknown, ...]" cannot be assigned to declared type "int"
> Type "int | bytes | str | Tuple[Unknown, ...]" cannot be assigned to type "int"
>     "bytes" is incompatible with "int"

For the third line, the message is almost identical except for "bytes" and "int" swapped:

> Expression of type "int | bytes | str | Tuple[Unknown, ...]" cannot be assigned to declared type "bytes"
> Type "int | bytes | str | Tuple[Unknown, ...]" cannot be assigned to type "bytes"
>     "int" is incompatible with "bytes"

That's right, the errors are the complete opposite of one another.

The code, however, runs fine on the board (if I change the third line from bytes to int, of course - int is the correct type here), which makes me think there is no actual error.

How do I make Pylance not raise this error?

Edited to add: It looks like pylance doesn't like when you use a function that can return different types with type hints, it tries to enforce ALL types instead of ANY type and fails.

For example, I've defined a function:

```
def read(self, count:int = 1) -> Union[int, bytes]:
```

that reads a number of bytes from the device. It returns either an integer if only a single byte is read, or a bytes string otherwise.

When trying to use it like this:

```
self._trim: bytes = self._i2c.read(0x18)
```

pylance raises an error that "int" is incompatible with "bytes".

So the question is now: is it possible to make Pylance work with multiple-valued type hints or am I better to just disable reportGeneralTypeIssues check in the project, as I'm using it all throughout?

Comment: My guess is that pylance doesn't know anything about Micropython-specific syntax. Probably the easiest solution is to add a `# type: ignore` to each line.

Comment: See my edit for additional details. It doesn't seem to be a Micropython-specific syntax.